# Com fazer consulta SQL adicionando coluna extra que não exite na tabela

Tags: firebird

Da para perceber que o campo `ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA,` está duplicado não é? pois bem, eu não sei como fazer isso mais preciso que o campo `ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA,` venha como `null`(Como se tivesse apagado os valores da coluna que está repetida) .

Abaixo é como está o Sql no sistema

```
SELECT
  ORCAMENTO.ID AS CODIGO,
  ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA AS DATA_ORCAMENTO,
  ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA,
  ORCAMENTO.VALOR_FINAL
FROM ORCAMENTO
  LEFT JOIN CLIENTES ON (ORCAMENTO.NOME_CLIENTE = CLIENTES.CLIENTE)   
  LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR ON (ORCAMENTO.ID_VENDEDOR  = VENDEDOR.ID)
WHERE
  ORCAMENTO.SITUACAO = 'IMPORTADO'
```

O resultado dela atualmente vem assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que minha consulta saia mais ou menos assim: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Tem como fazer isso?
- Como seria?

Monde o Titulo da pergunta para melhor entendimento.

Comment: O que significa "dois campos iguais sendo que um deles será null"? Se um deles é null então nunca será igual a outro campo, mesmo que o conteúdo do outro seja null. Se deseja testar se o conteúdo de um campo é NULL use: `... campo IS NULL ...`. Atenção para o fato de que seu campo DATA_VENDA não está duplicado, apenas o conteúdo das linhas listadas é NULL.

Comment: Vejo que não leu ou se quer visualizou o que estou perguntando...
se verificar o que esta na msg entendera o que quero. seja menos literal e mais racional.

Comment: a imagem é só uma ilustração de como que quero que fique não é real com o minimo de conhecimento saberia apenas vendo a consulta acima.

Comment: assim fica muito fácil sair negativando todo tipo de pergunta só pelo titulo sem analisar o conteúdo da pergunta.

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei sua pergunta, apenas comentei que talvez você não compreenda o significado de NULL.

Comment: isso não faz o menor sentido, se o campo data_venda tem que ser null não deve ser o mesmo campo que está na tabela. basta fazer `... data_venda as data_orcamento, null as data_venda ...`.  usando suas palavras "com o minimo de conhecimento saberia"

Comment: O que eu preciso é limpara a copia do campo para ficar null

Comment: o código q coloquei acima, faz isso.

Comment: O campo da da venda não tem que ser eu só estou adicionado uma coluna a mais.

Comment: então é só fazer o que falei e adicionar uma coluna como null... `SELECT
  ORCAMENTO.ID AS CODIGO,
  ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA AS DATA_ORCAMENTO,
  NULL AS DATA_VENDA,
  ORCAMENTO.VALOR_FINAL
FROM ORCAMENTO
  LEFT JOIN CLIENTES ON (ORCAMENTO.NOME_CLIENTE = CLIENTES.CLIENTE)   
  LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR ON (ORCAMENTO.ID_VENDEDOR  = VENDEDOR.ID)
WHERE
  ORCAMENTO.SITUACAO = 'IMPORTADO'` essa é a única opção para o que está querendo, se não for isso tente enteder e explicar melhor o que está querendo.

Comment: nem tudo na vida Faz sentido, o importante é resultado final. e com relação a o conhecimento que eu falei acima o minimo de conhecente para se entender o que está sendo proposto. se eu tivesse conhecimento de com fazer isso não teria perguntado.

Comment: De qualquer forma me ajudou e muito.
Muito obrigado.

Comment: poderia reescrever sua pergunta como "trazer dois campos iguais mas diferentes" e isso não faz o menor sentido. Aqui só temos a informação postada na pergunta e boa vontade de muitas pessoas querendo ajudar, e você "cobrou" o mínimo de conhecimento para interpretar sua pergunta o que foi bem rude. Sobre a solução, disponha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  ORCAMENTO.ID AS CODIGO,
  ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA AS DATA_ORCAMENTO,
  NULL AS DATA_VENDA,
  ORCAMENTO.VALOR_FINAL
FROM ORCAMENTO
  LEFT JOIN CLIENTES ON (ORCAMENTO.NOME_CLIENTE = CLIENTES.CLIENTE)   
  LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR ON (ORCAMENTO.ID_VENDEDOR  = VENDEDOR.ID)
WHERE
  ORCAMENTO.SITUACAO = 'IMPORTADO'
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa! Veja bem você pode por assim na sua consulta

```
SELECT
  ORCAMENTO.ID AS CODIGO,
  ORCAMENTO.DATA_VENDA AS DATA_ORCAMENTO,
  CAST(NULL AS TIMESTAMP) AS DATA_VENDA,
  ORCAMENTO.VALOR_FINAL
FROM ORCAMENTO
  LEFT JOIN CLIENTES ON (ORCAMENTO.NOME_CLIENTE = CLIENTES.CLIENTE)   
  LEFT JOIN VENDEDOR ON (ORCAMENTO.ID_VENDEDOR  = VENDEDOR.ID)
WHERE
  ORCAMENTO.SITUACAO = 'IMPORTADO'
```

Caso precise que seu capo tenha o menso tipo da coluna que está duplicando, você pode criar sua coluna virtual do tipo desejado. 
[`CAST` converte uma expressão no tipo de dados desejado. Se a conversão não for possível, será gerado um erro.](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd20-cast.html)